# SSIS writing window username instead of service account while logging

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have implemented a SSIS 2008 package using BIDS. My package currently logs exceptions and information to the database. I am running the package via a SQL Job. I have configured the job to run using a service account. The problem that I am facing is that when the logs are written, I am seeing my windows credentials written to the username column instead of service account credentials. I am running the job via SSMS using my windows credentials. I have been told that Jobs would run via any DBA guy and they may not log in using Service account.

Following are the steps I followed for the job to run as service account.

1. Created a credential with the service account as identity.
2. Created a proxy associating with the credential.
3. Configured the job to use the proxy account.

Below is the connection string from my package. I had removed Integrated Security=SSPI; and provided the userid and password of the service account but got an error message saying incorrect login.

```
<DTS:Property DTS:Name="ConnectionString">Data Source=xxxxxxxxx;User ID=;Initial Catalog=xxxxxx;Provider=SQLNCLI10.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;Application Name=xxxxxx-{452DA0BD-2ACF-4780-9DB0-5A64ABB406A1}xxxxxx\xxxxxx.xxxxxxx;Auto Translate=False;</DTS:Property>
```

Another thing that I have noticed is the creator name in the package is having my windows username. I tried updating that but no luck.

The errors are logged using event handlers

Event handler
[image][image]

The connection string in the dtscConfig file

```
Data Source=xxx\xxx;Initial Catalog=xxx;Provider=SQLNCLI10.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;Application Name=xxx\xxxxxxx;Auto Translate=False;
```

Comment: Inside the package, what is the value of the `ProtectionLevel` property?  Also, is your AD account a member of any of the [SQLAgent Roles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/agent/sql-server-agent-fixed-database-roles)?

Comment: who is the owner of the sqljob,also can you share how you are lgging username

Comment: The protection level of the package is DontSaveSensitive

Comment: The sql job is set to run as the service account.

Comment: The errors are handled using event handlers. Updated the post to show that

Comment: The creator name in the package is not service account. Its is my windows account.

Comment: I have updated the post with the connection string that is used in the dtsConfig file

Comment: if you schedule the job to run instead of executing it under your credential while logged into SSMS what do you get? The security context is not the same when you execute a job as when the SQL Agent does hence your credentials would be stored if you execute it.  If you look at job history you can also see the difference.  Post your dbo.InsertLog code and we can say with more certainty

Comment: How do you execute the package?  Only from hard disk, job or integration services?

Comment: I think owner is different from "run as". I had some issues with that some time ago

Comment: I have created the sql job and scheduled it to run the package. Even if I job runs as scheduled  and though the run as is set as service account it still shows the windows account login.

Answer (score 3):

I have fixed the issue. I am passing system:username in parameter to the stored procedure which has solved the issue